# Joining unique variable entries

Tags: stata

I am trying to join several string variables (`c1`, `c2` etc.):

```
AKJ OFE ETH AKJ AKJ
345 952 319 123 345
```

I can join them with the following command:

```
generate c = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5
```

How can I join only their unique entries?

```
AKJ OFE ETH
345 952 319 123
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is the following:

```
clear

input str3(c1 c2 c3 c4 c5)
AKJ OFE ETH AKJ AKJ
345 952 319 123 345
end

local vars c2 c3 c4 c5
local dvars c1

generate tempc1 = c1

foreach var of local vars {
    generate temp`var' = `var'
    foreach dvar of local dvars {
        replace temp`var' = "" if `var' == `dvar'
    }
    local dvars `dvars' `var'
}

egen c = concat(temp*), punct(" ")
drop temp*

list

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |  c1    c2    c3    c4    c5                 c |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. | AKJ   OFE   ETH   AKJ   AKJ       AKJ OFE ETH |
  2. | 345   952   319   123   345   345 952 319 123 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: hi i've to put all columns in local and then I see too many variables error.

Comment: You can solve the first problem with the `ds` command and the second by moving the `drop` command within the loop to drop each new variable individually.

Comment: Note that in Stata there are no columns, only variables.

Comment: In practice you check to see if the second to last variables are the same as the first. That works in this example, but the recipe is not general enough. You need to check if each variable from the second onwards is not the same as any of the preceding variables.

Comment: Apologies, the above comment is correct.  There was a line missing where the local `dvars` should be updated in each loop to check each variable from the second onwards.  This is edited in the above code.